# Involutions of binary sextic forms

Tags: invariant-theory

Let $F(x,y) = a_6 x^6 + a_5 x^5 y + \cdots + a_1 xy^5 + a_0 y^6$ be a binary sextic form with complex coefficients. Let $V_\mathbb{C}$ be the space over $\mathbb{C}$ of binary sextic forms. It is known that if $F$ has an involution, i.e. there is an order two element $U \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ which fixes $F$ by substitution, then $F$ lies on a hypersurface $\mathbb{H}$ of $V_\mathbb{C}$ of degree 15. This is attributed to Hermite, which is why the hypersurface is called $\mathbb{H}$. It is known that this hypersurface contains hundreds of terms at least and it is not feasible to write it down explicitly.

However, I have problems tracing down a proper reference describing what $\mathbb{H}$ is. This paper (http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/1008.3117.pdf) describes $\mathbb{H}$ as above, but does not give any more details. It cited further information in two other papers, both of which I checked (including Salmon's seminal treatise), but I did not find any information at the section cited in the paper. It is likely that my version of Salmon's book is not the right one.

Is there any modern reference/interpretation for this hypersurface?

Comment: My paper with Chipalkatti refers to my co-author's article on the degree 18 of the binary quintic, not sextic. The latter is due to Hermite. I actually don't know who first discovered the degree 15 invariant for sextics. What kind of info would you like on this degree 15 invariant?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: basically just enough to know how to describe it convincingly. Much appreciated!